# Using trustAsHTML for an array of Objects

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm attempting to feed an array of objects from an Angular Controller to an `ng-repeat` directive.

The objects returned in the array have several properties, a few of which may contain HTML that needs to be output by the result of `ng-repeat`. I can't seem to figure out how to `trustAsHTML` the entire object that is returned.

My view looks like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in searchedUsers" ng-bind-html="user">
```

I've attempted it like this:

```
$scope.searchedUsers = data;

for(var user in $scope.searchedUsers){
    $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.searchedUsers[user].matched);
    $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.searchedUsers[user].unmatched);
}
```

And also attempted structuring my directives like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in searchedUsers"><a href="#"><span ng-bind-html="user.matched">{{user.matched}}</span> <span ng-bind-html="user.unmatched">{{user.unmatched}}</span></a></li>
```

But I get the error back:

```
Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.
```

The JSON object I'm using is as follows:

```
[{"id":2,"name":"Jonny","email":"jonnyasmar@me.com","created_at":"2015-10-25 00:58:10","updated_at":"2015-10-25 02:11:59","matched":"jonny<span class=\"match\">as<\/span>mar@me.com","unmatched":"Jonny"}]
```

Any idea how this can be accomplished or do I need to rethink my implementation?

Comment: can you to include the json object on your question? we don't to know if your object is searchedUsers[] or searchedUsers.matched[]...

Comment: Sorry -- I totally didn't realize that inconsistency x_x I've added the json object to the question. Thanks!

Comment: do you have included the $sanitize js? I'm trying to make an example on jsbin

Comment: No, I'm not using sanitize js. Should I be?

Comment: yes, it's necessary... I will make a complete answer

Comment: Hmm -- gotcha. I will look into it as well in the meantime. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include ngSanitize js and dependency:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

and, on module:

```
angular.module('yourModule', ['ngSanitize'])
```

after this, the ng-bind-html will work. For example:

```
<div ng-bind-html="user.matched"></div>
```

take a look at complete code on [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/xuvuliz/edit?html,js,output)